# CFXML code to produce hexBinary on one of my xpaths

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I need to produce the following xml packet to post to hudson.  The log xml item will essentially have lines of console output.  Can anyone help with the ColdFusion/Java to correctly encode that item

```
<run>
  <log encoding='hexBinary'>...hex binary encoded console output...</log>
  <result>... integer indicating the error code. 0 is success and everything else is failure</result>
  <duration>... milliseconds it took to execute this run ...</duration>
</run>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<CFXML>` tag would be the easiest way to construct a XML object in CFML.

hexBinary can be encoded using: `BinaryEncode(yourBinaryData, "Hex")`

`<cftimer>` can be used to measure the time took to execute the section of code in between the tags.  Or `GetTickCount()`

Comment: You can't use BinaryEncode on a string. I have a string that I need to encode to form the log key data.

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but does the toBase64(...) function do what you want?